# Как передать в input разные data при открытии popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

На html несколько товаров:

```
<div class="order_button">
    <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-1">заказать</a>
</div>
<div class="order_button">
    <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-2">заказать</a>
</div>
```

При клике на ссылку "заказать" открывается модальное окно:

```
<div class="popup_bg" id="cart">    
    <form class="popup" action="" method="POST">
        <a href="#products" class="close-popup">&#10006</a>
        <p>Оформить заявку</p>
        <input id="product" type="text" class="form-text" value="" readonly>
        <button type="submit">заказать</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

input отметил как readonly, с целью автоматического присвоения данных с data-product. К сожалению, при открытии модального окна, данные в input остаются пустыми.
Сам код по открытию модального окна следующий:

```
let popupBg = document.querySelector('.popup_bg');
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let openPopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.open_popup');
let closePopupButton = document.querySelector('.close-popup');


openPopupButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        popupBg.classList.add('active');
        popup.classList.add('active');
        let product = $(this).data('product');
        $('#product').val(product);
        return false;
    })
});

closePopupButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popupBg.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target === popupBg) {
        popupBg.classList.remove('active');
        popup.classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

Кто сможет помочь с решением данной задачи?
Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что используете стрелочную функцию `button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {...` у нее `this` ссылается на `Window`.

Если используете стрелочную функцию тогда используйте `e.target`.
Если нужен `this` тогда прописываете `function (e)....`

**PS: 29.06.2022**

Вот пример реализации с `this` - стрелочная функция

```js
let popupBg = document.querySelector('.popup_bg');
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let openPopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.open_popup');
let closePopupButton = document.querySelector('.close-popup');


openPopupButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    popupBg.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
    let product = $(e.target).data('product');
    $('#product').val(product);
    return false;
  })
});

closePopupButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupBg.classList.remove('active');
  popup.classList.remove('active');
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target === popupBg) {
    popupBg.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="order_button">
  <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-1">заказать</a>
</div>
<div class="order_button">
  <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-2">заказать</a>
</div>

<div class="popup_bg" id="cart">
  <form class="popup" action="" method="POST">
    <a href="#products" class="close-popup">&#10006</a>
    <p>Оформить заявку</p>
    <input id="product" type="text" class="form-text" value="" readonly>
    <button type="submit">заказать</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Вот пример реализации с `this` - в `function(e){.....}`

```js
let popupBg = document.querySelector('.popup_bg');
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let openPopupButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.open_popup');
let closePopupButton = document.querySelector('.close-popup');


openPopupButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    popupBg.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
    let product = $(this).data('product');
    $('#product').val(product);
    return false;
  })
});

closePopupButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupBg.classList.remove('active');
  popup.classList.remove('active');
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target === popupBg) {
    popupBg.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="order_button">
  <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-1">заказать</a>
</div>
<div class="order_button">
  <a href="" class="open_popup" data-product="Товар-2">заказать</a>
</div>

<div class="popup_bg" id="cart">
  <form class="popup" action="" method="POST">
    <a href="#products" class="close-popup">&#10006</a>
    <p>Оформить заявку</p>
    <input id="product" type="text" class="form-text" value="" readonly>
    <button type="submit">заказать</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: немного не понял, чтобы использовать this мне по другому нужно выводить модальное окно?

Comment: @Rahym автор сказал что `this` в данном контексте ссылается на объект `window`, а чтобы `this` ссылался на текущий элемент, вам нужно использовать **не** стрелочные функции, а обыкновенные (пример: `function (e) { ... }`), либо как упомянул автор, можно использовать `e.target`

Comment: @ΝNL993 все верно, спасибо за объяснение

Comment: @Rahym разобрались?

Comment: @АлександрСычёв счс буду тестить, по результатам отпишусь, спасибо за отзыв!

Comment: @АлександрСычёв не получилось(((

Comment: @Rahym добавил пример в ответ - посмотрите